# Add elements to a sublist of a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, sublist

I don't know if this question is too easy but I haven't found anything at the internet to solve this problem.

I have a List of Lists where I add three sublists.

```
 List<List<DateTime>> myList= new List<List<DateTime>>();

 while (countNeededSubLists != 0)
 {
   myList.Add(new List<DateTime>());
   countNeededSubLists--;
 }
```

Now I want to simply add a new Date to the sublist which is at index 1 of my list. How to achieve that and what is the correct syntax for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myList[1].Add(new DateTime());
```

Comment: Oh I had an error in it. Now it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to always check if it is not null, like this:

```
if(!myList.Any())
    return;

myList.[1].Add(new DateTime());
```